# CondaRevisionError: Cannot revert to 3, since XX is not in repodata

Tags: conda, rollback

I have an environment in conda, that has been screwed up after an install.

When I try rolling it back to its previous state I get an error :

```
CondaRevisionError: Cannot revert to 3, since anaconda::certifi-2018.11.29-py27_0 is not in repodata.
```

I cannot revert it back. Has anyone ever had this issue ?

Comment: Maybe try [manually downloading the tarball](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/certifi/files?version=2018.11.29) and dropping it into your `miniconda3/pkgs/` directory first?

Comment: I ended up reverting manually all the changes using `conda install` but that's a real shame this functionality doesn't work, even though it is so useful ..